# CORS issues: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header mustn't contain multiple values

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I want to allow my server to let two different domains read data without getting a CORS issue.

Therefore, I wrote the following code line (in node.js):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", ["http://ServerA:3000", "http://ServerB:3000"]);
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
   next();
});
```

However, when I sent the request by the browser I got the error:

> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values
>   'http://ServerA:3000, http://ServerB:3000', but only one is
>   allowed. Origin 'http://ServerB:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

My question is how to define 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin for more than one origin. I don't want to use '*' because it is too liberal.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to check your current origin with the ones that you have in the config:

```
let allowedOrigins = ["http://ServerA:3000", "http://ServerB:3000"]
let origin = req.headers.origin;
if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin); // restrict it to the required domain
}
```

The header expects only one value of the origin, or a wildcard sign, that's why it's not working for you

Comment: what does the variable 'origin' mean ?

Comment: @CrazySynthax it's what you have in the origin header of the request, or the other way that you determine the origin of the request, I'v added the relevant code

Comment: @CrazySynthax this would be the url of header request like http://ServerB:3000, which you want allow to access resource.