# CORS issue in (Nodejs + Angular 6 + socket.io)

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, cors

We are facing CORS issue in Angular 6 using socket.io client when we are trying to connect to the server.

The error we are getting in the console of browser.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://********.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3jTiAZ' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: 

The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

 The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

Here is the server code

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const conn = app.listen("3000")
const io = require('socket.io').listen(conn);

io.origins('*:*') 

var connectioncheck = io.of('/check-connection');
connectioncheck.on('connection', function (socket) {
   console.log('user  connected');
});
```

Here is frontend code using simple html and js

```
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/socket.io-client@2/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
var socket = io.connect('http://********.com/check-connection');
socket.emit('connection', "hello",function(db){
        console.log(db);
        console.log("data from callback");
    });
```

Comment: Did you try using cors by npm? https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: yes I try but did not work

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://******.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3jY9aF' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, http://localhost:4200', but only one is allowed.

I am getting this when i try cors

Comment: I think you should use NPM CORS in a way that stated in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910130/cors-issues-the-access-control-allow-origin-header-mustnt-contain-multiple-v

Comment: I try it but not working any other solution

Comment: I used the NPM of CORS and issue is resolve but as I also running the Apache on same server for PHP and also sending some custom headers in response using apache  thats the reason i not able resolve the issue  



thanks guys 4 support

Comment: CODE used.  ------------>

app.use(cors()); 

app.all('/*', function (request, response, next) { 

response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

 response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With"); response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST", "PUT", "DELETE"); 
//response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true'); 
next(); 

});

Comment: You can answer to your question and accept it if you find a solution instead of adding comment it would be better to reach out to other people having similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

According to comments you gave above I think you should use NPM CORS in a way like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910130/cors-issues-the-access-control-allow-origin-header-mustnt-contain-multiple-v)

```
let allowedOrigins = ["http://ServerA:3000", "http://ServerB:3000"]
let origin = req.headers.origin;
if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin); // restrict it to the required domain
}
```